# Is it possible to have icon centered in constraint layout unless overlapping textview

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to keep an icon centered inside a constraint layout while making it always stay over some text view that is on the bottom of the constraint layout (this is a very simplified version of my actual issue but represents the problem equally). The text in the bottom can be large enough to go over the center of the layout, in which case I want the icon to be shifted upwards.

In order to relate the icon's bottom to both the center and the text view's top, I am using a guideline in the center of the layout and a barrier to catch the top of the text view or the top of the guideline, whichever is higher.

The problem is that half the icon is under the guideline so the text still is overlapped by the icon. And the icon only shifts upward when the text view's top goes over the guideline. Alternatively, I can set the bottom of the icon on top of the guideline, so the text view is never overlapped, but the icon is not exactly centered.

This is the current status of the layout with all the items:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_play"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/barrier"
        />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="top"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="guide,text" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guide"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Temporibus ea quasi ut dolores quae qui. Et dolor sit voluptatem fugit. Possimus nulla molestias maxime. Distinctio perferendis veniam modi sint numquam dolores esse. Minus consequuntur mollitia asperiores praesentium non minus. Temporibus ea quasi ut dolores quae qui. Et dolor sit voluptatem fugit. Et dolor sit voluptatem fugit."
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I found a (not great) solution, which is adding top padding to the text view half the size of the image view. I would prefer to avoid such a hack and find a good implementation instead. Is it possible?

To help understand the issue, here are some images from the UI designer in Android Studio:

The hopeful result with short text:
[image: Icon centered, short text not overlapped]

Which causes problems when text is long:
[image: Icon shifted upwards, long text overlapped]

If an icon is not centered when the text is short:
[image: Icon not centered, short text not overlapped]

We don't get the problem when the text is long:
[image: Icon shifted upwards, long text not overlapped]

Comment: So to confirm, you want the icon always centered in the CL, unless the textview’s top edge goes past center, and then the bottom edge of the icon should hug the top edge of the textview, correct?

Comment: @flopshot That is nearly correct, as the icon is centered, its bottom is under the center guideline. I want the icon to be shifted upwards when the text view reaches the icon, no the center. That would be too late.

Comment: An alternative hack I have found to be a bit better than the one I mentioned, is to add an empty view over the TextView that has the height of half the icon. The barrier then is calculated to that empty view.  That way the icon will never cover the text and remain centered.

As it is nonetheless a hack, I don't really want to consider it as a solution, a cleaner solution would be appreciated.

Comment: @JayKumarPanera Oh thank you, that has helped me solved the issue. Your comment has shown me the true path... Sarcasm aside, I would be happy to hear any improvement you think I could apply, but sincerely, your comment is useless as it is. So how do you think that the Guideline is supposed to be used?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `paddingTop` of `TextView` to the half of `ImageView`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Temporibus ea quasi ut dolores quae qui. Et dolor sit voluptatem fugit. Possimus nulla molestias maxime. Distinctio perferendis veniam modi sint numquam dolores esse. Minus consequuntur mollitia asperiores praesentium non minus. Temporibus ea quasi ut dolores quae qui. Et dolor sit voluptatem fugit. Et dolor sit voluptatem fugit."
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: This will unfortunately not solve the issue, it would end up like the third and fourth screenshot. It will work when the text is long, but not when it is short, as the icon is not actually centered. At least that is what I see when testing in Android Studio.

Comment: Still not really fixed. I didn't make a big point of it, so it is easy to miss, but I did propose this paddingTop hack as a possible (not really great) solution. It works, but it feels like a bad solution. And even more so, as there are more elements in the real layout, the padding interferes with those. A better alternative that I wrote in a comment is using a simple View that has that size and goes on top of the TextView.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand why you are calling this solution a "hack". Adding padding to a view is a normal action. Many layouts must be adjusted in this way to meet their needs. In your case, you have a fixed centred Image size (40dp). So, you need to compensate this in some way. Of course, using a View instead of padding is also possible, but this means to add a new object to your layout...

Comment: I call it a hack because it requires adding a property that is not meant for this use really. Plus it affects all other views that related to this one, breaking the previous implementation. Adding the extra view is also problematic in its own as you say, but it doesn't break anything else.

The solution I expected is more on making the constraint layout (or any other view) somehow relate both elements only in cases that they get in each other's ways.